# How to insert CSV value into Selenium XPATH string?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, xpath

I am trying to modify an XPATH click command based on a line value in a CSV. In the code below, I'd like to replace "34" with the csv value.

I have the CSV imported into selenium, how should I go about dynamically inserting the CSV variable into the "34" place?

```
companystateselect = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/mat-option[34]/span")
    companystateselect.click()
```

CSV Code

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
```

CODE THAT WORKS

```
companystateselect = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/mat-option[{0}]/span".format(line[1]))
        companystateselect.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to insert variables into strings with Python.
You can use this:

```py
variable = '34'
companystateselect = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/mat-option[{0}]/span".format(variable))
companystateselect.click()
```

**UPD**
in case each `line` in your code is exactly the value you want to use with your XPath locator it can be used as folowing:

```py
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        companystateselect = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/mat-option[{0}]/span".format(line))
        companystateselect.click()
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I make the variable change based on my csv?

Comment: Depends on how you implemented importing data from CVS into your selenium code. You didn't share that...

Comment: No, please put that into the question to make it readable

Comment: Also, does each line there contains single value you want to directly insert into the XPath locator?

Comment: for that column yes. it is selecting from a dropdown based on the variable. varies based on the column though, some are just SendKeys and some are radio buttons etc.

Comment: OK, I used it here as if they all are just a string. In case these are numbers etc. you will need to cast the variable to make it to be `string`

Comment: In case some of them are `sendkeys` etc this makes it all more complex. Also you will possibly need to put delays between clicks.

Comment: some of them are sendkeys etc, but should that effect this one piece of code? Just hoping to insert the csv column into the xpath. The initial "variable" code above worked, but how would I link that variable to a column in the CSV?

Comment: I figured this out, solution posted above, thank you very much for your help.